# WordPress: вывод записей категории

Tags: wordpress

Всем привет, вопрос по WordPress. Редактирую шаблон `category.php`, код ниже выводит все записи, которые добавлены. Как вывести записи только из той категории, на странице которой мы находимся?

```
<?php
    $mainquery = new WP_Query(array(
        'post_type' => 'post', 
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
    ));
    if ( $mainquery->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $mainquery->have_posts() ) {
            $mainquery->the_post(); 
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Во время вызова `category.php` ID категории находится в глобальной переменной `$cat`. Ваш код нужно дополнить одной строчкой: `'cat' => $cat`.

```
<?php
    $mainquery = new WP_Query(array(
        'post_type' => 'post', 
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'cat' => $cat
    ));
    if ( $mainquery->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $mainquery->have_posts() ) {
            $mainquery->the_post(); 
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: то что нужно, большое спасибо

Comment: Если ответ работает, его можно отметить как принятый (зеленая галочка)